# Place Navbar over Logo and maintain position when scaled

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to lay the navbar over the logo so that it is precisely  under the "g"?

It needs to maintain that location even when the browser is resized and on different screen sizes and also not affect the content that will be underneath.

The logo image scales down to fit the screen.

---

[image: navbar]

---

Browser Scaled Down

[image: navbar scaled]

---

https://jsfiddle.net/jypwoaet/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="logo">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3SBvB3a.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        About
      </li>
      <li>
        Gallery
      </li>
      <li>
        Contact
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

#logo {
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

#logo img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -12vh auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: add this margin-top:1px; to #nav and give a try

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

#logo {
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

#logo img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -16px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="logo">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3SBvB3a.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        About
      </li>
      <li>
        Gallery
      </li>
      <li>
        Contact
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

try this, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jypwoaet/3/)

Comment: That almost did it. I need more margin so the nav overlaps the logo. When I changed it to -60px and scaled the window size down, it goes beyond the "g". https://jsfiddle.net/nk7pkLvr/

Comment: Scale the screen, notice how the content goes under the Nav when positioned with absolute. https://jsfiddle.net/nk7pkLvr/5/